# Java 8 Stream - GroupingBy Class

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, java-stream

i have a problem with groupingBy method.
I use an example:
Suppose to have a `List<Person>` where `Person.class` and `City.class` are like this

```
class Person{
   String name;
   String surname;
   City city;
}

class City{
   String name;
   String postalCode;
}
```

I would group the list by `city.postalcode` and do somthing like this:

```
 List<Person> myList = ...some persons here...
 Map<City,List<Person>> groupMap = myList.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person));
```

Obviously this not work because `groupingBy` don't know how to group by an object.
I would do something like this `Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.city.postalcode)` but with this produces a map of type `Map<String,List<Person>>` and not  `Map<City,List<Person>>`

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

For use `groupingBy` on a class this must simply implement correctly  `equals` and `hashcode`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person)
Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.city.postalcode)
```

You want to group by city? Don't group by person, or by postal code. Group by the city, exactly as you've stated.

```
Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.city)
```

As you state in your question, `City` should override `equals` and `hashCode`.

```
class City {
    String name;
    String postalCode;

    @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof City)) {
            return false;
        }

        City that = (City) obj;

        return Objects.equals(this.name, that.name)
            && Objects.equals(this.postalCode, that.postalCode)
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, postalCode);
    }
}
```